# How to loop a dataTable and disable a link on specific rows of it?

Tags: jquery, datatables

There is a `dataTable` :

```
<div id="tabl">
    <table id="table_tabl" class="display striped bordered" data-searching="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Salle</th>
                <th>Table</th>
                <th>R&eacute;serv&eacute;e</th>
                <th>Date d&eacute;but</th>
                <th>Date fin</th>
                <th>Action</th> // containing link-buttons "update","delete","register","unregister"
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```js
$('#table_tabl').dataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sUrl": "<?php  echo RP_LANG ?>fr_FR.txt"
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    ajax: "<?php  echo RP_SSP ?>server_processing_reservTables.php",  
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ 
        "aTargets": [5],
        "mData": 5,
        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
            var table_ = '\''+full [0]+'\'';
            return '<div style="text-align:center;"><a href="Restaurantreservation/modifierReservTable/'+ data +'" title="Update"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' + 
                '<a href="#" id="staticDialog" onclick="afficheDlg('+ data +','+table_+')" style="color: red; font-size: 14px;" title="Delete"><i class="icon-cancel-2"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="Restaurantreservation/affecterReservTable/'+ data +'" title="Register"><i class="icon-locked"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="Restaurantreservation/annulerReservTable/'+ data +'" title="Unregister"><i class="icon-unlocked"></i></a></div>';
            },
        }],
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [10, 25,50,100, -1], 
            [10, 25,50,100, "Tout"]
        ]
    });
```

As you can see there are the link-buttons `icon-pencil`, `icon-cancel-2`, `icon-locked` and `icon-unlocked` inside the `Action` column.
I want to disable the `icon-locked` link-button if the value of the third column `R&eacute;serv&eacute;e` equals `oui`. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about this but you can just try once as below:

```
$('#table_tabl').dataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sUrl": "<?php  echo RP_LANG ?>fr_FR.txt"
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    ajax: "<?php  echo RP_SSP ?>server_processing_reservTables.php",  
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ 
        "aTargets": [5],
        "mData": 5,
        "mRender": function (data, type, column) {
            var table_ = '\''+column[0]+'\'';
            if(column[2] == 'oui'){
                return '<div style="text-align:center;"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>' + 
                '<i class="icon-cancel-2"></i>' +
                '<i class="icon-locked"></i>' +
                '<i class="icon-unlocked"></i></div>';

            }else{
                return '<div style="text-align:center;"><a href="Restaurantreservation/modifierReservTable/'+ data +'" title="Update"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' + 
                '<a href="#" id="staticDialog" onclick="afficheDlg('+ data +','+table_+')" style="color: red; font-size: 14px;" title="Delete"><i class="icon-cancel-2"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="Restaurantreservation/affecterReservTable/'+ data +'" title="Register"><i class="icon-locked"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="Restaurantreservation/annulerReservTable/'+ data +'" title="Unregister"><i class="icon-unlocked"></i></a></div>';
            }            

            },
        }],
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [10, 25,50,100, -1], 
            [10, 25,50,100, "Tout"]
        ]
    });
```

Comment: your response is quite exact , but it needs removing the `href` attribute in the if region accordingly :) , and at that time it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an id attribute to your third column as

`<th id="dependency-check">R&eacute;serv&eacute;e</th>`

You can write a small function to check the value in third column and disable the `icon-locked` button as:

`function disableIconLocked() {
    var value = $('th#dependency-check').text()
    if(value === 'oui')
        //select icon-locked button as $('.icon-locked')
        //write the logic to disable it

}`

You can then call this function wherever the value for third column is set/changed and you need to disable `icon-locked` button.

Comment: I want to disable `icon-locked` button in real-time when the dataTable is displaying data. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but you can just try once as below using `$.when` and `.done` hoping that `dataTables` returns promises

```
$.when(
    $('#table_tabl').dataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "oLanguage": {
        "sUrl": "<?php  echo RP_LANG ?>fr_FR.txt"
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        ajax: "<?php  echo RP_SSP ?>server_processing_reservTables.php",  
        "aoColumnDefs": [{ 
            "aTargets": [5],
            "mData": 5,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                 var table_ = '\''+full [0]+'\'';
                 return '<div style="text-align:center;"><a href="Restaurantreservation/modifierReservTable/'+ data +'" title="Update"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' + 
                '<a href="#" id="staticDialog" onclick="afficheDlg('+ data +','+table_+')" style="color: red; font-size: 14px;" title="Delete"><i class="icon-cancel-2"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="Restaurantreservation/affecterReservTable/'+ data +'" title="Register"><i class="icon-locked"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="Restaurantreservation/annulerReservTable/'+ data +'" title="Unregister"><i class="icon-unlocked"></i></a></div>';
               },
          }],
          "aLengthMenu": [
            [10, 25,50,100, -1], 
            [10, 25,50,100, "Tout"]
          ]
      });
).done(function(){
     $.each($('#table_tabl tbody tr td:nth-child(2)',function(){
          if($(this).text()=='oui')
               $(this).closest('tr').find('a [title="Register"]').css('disabled',true); 
              //find anchor with title=Register and disable the whole anchor
     })     
})
```

Just give a try and let me know for any issues